# XMLHttpRequest cannot load file response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

I recently transferred a website (from the same host, just a couple of folders down) and now my ajax script stopped working.

I get the following error for each script that needs to be loaded:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.website.nl/includes/loadmore.php. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)
```

What could be causing this? This is my ajax script:

```
(function(){
/*
Meer websites laden
*/
var limit = 3;
var offset = 0;
var i =0;
$('#loadmore').click(function() {
    limit = 3;
    limit = 4;
    if(i == 0) {
        offset += 3;
    } else {
        offset += 4;
    }
    i++;

    ajax();

});

var posts = document.getElementById('loadnews');

function ajax() {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'includes/loadmore.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: {limit: limit, offset: offset},
    success: function(data){
        var newWrapper = document.createElement('div')
        //add class to newWrapper or whatever
        newWrapper.innerHTML=data;
        loadnews.appendChild(newWrapper);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
              if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                   alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
               } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                   alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
               } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                   alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
               } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                   alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
               } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                   alert('Time out error.');
               } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                   alert('Ajax request aborted.');
               } else {
                   alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
               }
           }
    }); 
}

ajax();
}());
```

I read something on changing the headers that are sent and allowing cross access, but I already do that in my htaccess file. It also doesn't really make sense to me since the files are still on the same host, just a different folder.

Like so:

```
#Cross site access toestaan
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" 
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: I did @CailinP but I can't remember what it was.

Answer (score 0):

looks like csrf issue so you are getting

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.website.nl/includes/loadmore.php. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)
```

mean you are at http://www.website.nl

try to send ajax request from http://website.nl